# redirecting images from other domain for SEO

Tags: html, node.js, seo

I have the images of my website stored on a different host (flickr) and stored in a database, Im happy with the way this works but someone told me it is bad for seo because if someone finds the image on google it'll direct to flickr and not to my website.

Now to bypass this problem, I was thinking of doing this:

```
routes.get('/img.jpg', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("http://lorempixel.com/300/300");
});
```

and when I do this:

```
<img src="/img.jpg">
```

I get my desired image, but does this fool the googlebot? And if not is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: What is _lorempixel.com_? Your domain or a link to flicrk?

Comment: A site that serves random images (lorem ipsum is nonsensical text, this the same for images), I used it to make the example less specific.

Comment: If you only serve images from the external website I don't think google will redirect to them. Imagine for example a cdn that serves static content, images are related to the web pages. Instead using flickr I think google can suppose the Image property is not yours and then redirects to flickr's home...